# Prompting user for new DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, console-application

I'm working on a project where I have to prompt a user a enter several dates. This is the code I came up with for prompting the user for the day, month, and year.

```
Console.WriteLine("Day: ");
var dateDay = Console.ReadLine();
var dateDayInt = Convert.ToInt32(dateDay);

Console.WriteLine("Month: ");
var dateMonth = Console.ReadLine();
var dateMonthInt = Convert.ToInt32(dateMonth);

Console.WriteLine("Year: ");
var dateYear = Console.ReadLine();
var dateyearInt = Convert.ToInt32(dateYear);

DateTime myDate = new DateTime(dateYearInt, dateMonthInt, dateDayInt, 00, 00, 00, 000);
```

I'm using this date in a method, so it needs to be in this format.

As you can see, it's a ton of repetitive code. If I even add one or two more dates, my project will become very cluttered. Let's say I need to get 20 dates. Is there an easier way to do this, like only having one prompt per date? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If your program is working, but just need a good clean up/efficiency tune up, http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is probably a better place for this type of question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not let them enter the entire date in one shot.

```
public DateTime GetDateTime()
{
    DateTime ret;
    while (true)
    {
        Console.Write("Date? ");
        var dte = Console.ReadLine();
        if (DateTime.TryParse(dte, out ret))
            return ret;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer. I would consider using DateTime.TryParseExact to avoid any ambiguities with the entered date format.

Comment: Yeah, their are a ton of ways to extend this including overloads to just return date or time portions.  But as it sits it should use the current culture of the system.